# Echarts confidence band

Tags: javascript, plot, graph, echarts

I'm new to Echarts and graph libraries in general.

I'm trying to create a line chart with what I've recently learned is called a confidence band to show min/max values for each point. I found this example: https://echarts.apache.org/examples/en/editor.html?c=confidence-band however, when I try to apply this idea to my chart, it doesn't display it correctly.

My three series of min/max/mean look like this:
[image]

However when I try to stack min and max and add an areaStyle to it, like in the example, it looks like this:
[image]

As I said, I'm new to this, so I have to admit that I'm not even 100% sure what *stacking* series even does, I was just following the example mentioned above.

My question is: what am I missing here, why does stacking mess up the max-series?

My Echarts options look like this:

```
this.options = {
  title: {
    text: ''
  },
  legend: {
    show: true
  },
  tooltip: {
    trigger: 'axis',
    axisPointer: {
      type: 'cross',
      animation: false,
      label: {
        backgroundColor: '#ccc',
        borderColor: '#aaa',
        borderWidth: 1,
        shadowBlur: 0,
        shadowOffsetX: 0,
        shadowOffsetY: 0,
        color: '#222'
      }
    }
  },
  toolbox: {
    show: true,
    feature: {
      ...features,
      brush: {
        show: false
      },
    }
  },
  xAxis: {
    type: 'category',
    boundaryGap: false,
    splitLine: {
      show: false
    },
    data: [],
    name: '',
    nameTextStyle: {
      fontWeight: 'bold'
    },
    min: 'dataMin',
    max: 'dataMax',
    scale: true,
    axisLabel: {
      formatter: value => {
        return `${value} m`;
      }
    }
  },
  yAxis: {
    type: 'value',
    name: '',
    nameTextStyle: {
      fontWeight: 'bold'
    },
    nameLocation: 'middle',
    nameGap: 60,
    axisLabel: {
      formatter: value => {
        return `${value} m/s`;
      }
    },
    splitNumber: 3,
    splitLine: {
      show: false
    }
  },
  dataZoom: [
    {
      type: 'slider',
      xAxisIndex: 0,
      filterMode: 'empty'
    },
    {
      type: 'slider',
      yAxisIndex: 0,
      filterMode: 'empty'
    }
  ],
  series: [
    {
      name: 'min',
      type: 'line',
      data: [],
      stack: 'confidence-band',
      symbol: 'none'
    },
    {
      name: 'max',
      type: 'line',
      data: [],
      areaStyle: {
        color: '#ccc'
      },
      stack: 'confidence-band',
      symbol: 'none'
    },
    {
      name: 'mean',
      type: 'line',
      data: [],
      hoverAnimation: false,
      symbolSize: 6,
      showSymbol: false
    }
  ]
};
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Stacking **ADDS** the values from each line together, and is meant more for cumulative reporting (Such as looking at cumulative sales from four categories of products with each sales amount stacked on top - the top of the stack is the total cumulative sale)

For a **min/max** band you need to stack `min` first then `max-min` on top.

*This stacks fine because max will always be larger than min.*

A subsequent problem here is that the tooltip now shows `max-min` and not the `max` value so a custom formatter is needed to show the correct value `(max-min) + min`