# echarts4R tooltip not updating/accurate

Tags: r, echarts, echarts4r

I have created the chart below with a forecast section using echarts4R, but the tooltip doesn't seem to be accurate - the label for the "Upper band" seems to be stuck on one value, and doesnt change like when I hover over other data points. Any idea why that is?

[image]

[image]

Below is a reproducible example:

```
dat <- data.frame(
time = as.Date(c("2015-09-01","2015-10-01","2015-11-01","2015-12-01","2016-01-01","2016-02-01",
  "2016-03-01","2016-04-01")),
Profit = c(58307.99, 54626.44,58675.40,44361.57,NA,NA,NA,NA),
Forecast = c(NA,NA,NA, 44361.57, 36500.09, 30506.53, 35241.72, 31922.28),
Lower_CI = c(NA,NA,NA, 22159.93, 22159.93, 16166.36, 20901.56, 17582.11),
Upper_CI = c(NA,NA,NA, 50840.26, 50840.26, 44846.69, 49581.89, 46262.44)
)

dat |>
  e_charts(x = time) |>
  e_line(serie = Profit) |>
  e_line(serie = Forecast) |>
  e_band(
    min = Lower_CI,
    max = Upper_CI,
    stack = "confidence-band",
    name = c("Lower bound", "Upper bound")) |>
  e_tooltip(formatter = e_tooltip_pointer_formatter("currency")) |>
  e_legend(show=FALSE) |>
  e_x_axis(time, axisPointer = list(show = TRUE))
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is that the value shown for the upper bound is the difference between the upper and the lower bound and according to your data this difference amounts to a constant value of 28680.

According to [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58282601/echarts-confidence-band) fixing the tooltip requires a custom JS formatter. An advantage of the custom formatter is that it allows for some further customization of the tooltip, e.g. in the code below I dropped all missing values from the tooltip:

```
library(echarts4r)

dat |>
  e_charts(x = time) |>
  e_line(serie = Profit) |>
  e_line(serie = Forecast) |>
  e_band(
    min = Lower_CI,
    max = Upper_CI,
    stack = "confidence-band",
    name = c("Lower bound", "Upper bound")
  ) |>
  e_tooltip(
    formatter = htmlwidgets::JS("
      function(params){
        let USDollar = new Intl.NumberFormat('en-US', {
            style: 'currency',
            currency: 'USD',
            maximumFractionDigits: 0
        });
      
        let tooltip = params[0].value[0];
        let value = 0;
        for (let i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
          if (i === 3) {
            value = Number(params[2].value[1]) + Number(params[3].value[1]);
          } else {
            value = Number(params[i].value[1])
          }
          if (params[i].value[1] !== null) {
            tooltip += '<br>' + params[i].marker;
            tooltip += params[i].seriesName + ': ';
            tooltip += USDollar.format(value);
          }
        }

        return(tooltip)
      }
    ")
  ) |>
  e_legend(show = FALSE) |>
  e_x_axis(time, axisPointer = list(show = TRUE))
```

[image]